# Powershell get file with last date included

Tags: powershell

I have saved a file like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $OSPathTemp |
    Rename-Item -NewName  {
        $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy') + $_.Extension
    }
```

How can I select this file again? I tried with:

```
$Path = "\\SRVSCCM01\_Source$\OS\REFWS2016" + '_' + { $_.LastWriteTime } + $_.Extension
```

The file is named: `REFWS2016_XXXXX.Wim`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart formatting issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by creating an array:

```
$arrayWimFiles = @()

$arrayWimFiles  = @(
Get-ChildItem -Path "$OSPathTemp" -recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'_'+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy')+$_.Extension}
)

$Windows10ENBase = $arrayWimFiles |  Where-Object { $_ -like "REFW10-X64EN-01*" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$WindowsSRV2016Base = $arrayWimFiles |  Where-Object { $_ -like "REFWS2016*" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple enough... add `-PassThru` to your `Rename-Item` and save the result in a variable.

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path $OSPathTemp |
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy') + $_.Extension
    } -PassThru
```

Then just reference `$File`.

Comment: Thanks, this works - but how do i separate them, if there are multiple files ?

Comment: i also need it from another path, as i moved the file from a temp folder after i rename it.. Is it possible to to extract it like this:

`\\SRVSCCM01\_Source$\OS\REFWS2016" + '_'+ {$_.LastWriteTime}  + $_.Extension `